Commutative algebra from Hungerford’s algebra
I just finished a course in abstract algebra (group theory, ring and module theory, field and Galois theory) from Hungerford’s algebra GTM. I want to study algebraic geometry, and commutative algebra is prerequisite for it. I know, Atiyah and Macdonald is a standard text to learn commutative algebra. Hungerford’s algebra contains a chapter on commutative algebra. Its section are: chain conditions, prime and primary ideal, primary decomposition, noetherian ring and modules, ring extension, dedekind domains, the Hilbert Nullstellensatz.
First three chapters of A&M is kind of overlapping material with ring and and module theory in Hungerford’s algebra (except exercises). Of course A&M contains more content than Hungerford. Question: Given the topics covered in Hungerford’s algebra, is it reasonably enough to start studying algebraic geometry from Hartshorne?

Most people learn classical algebraic geometry before they learn scheme theory. Since Hartshorne takes the scheme-theoretic approach, you might want to learn the more basic stuff first. (It's not a logical prerequisite, but it does help in understanding the motivation behind what scheme theory is trying to abstract.) Perhaps consulting this MathOverflow thread will help.

@Joe Thank you so much for the link. I have read in some post that chapter 1 of Hartshorne is classical algebraic geometry.

Yes, that's right – but I think the first chapter is meant to be a review of classical algebraic geometry; it's not really intended to be the place where you first acquaint yourself with it. Since you seem to know quite a lot of commutative algebra, perhaps starting somewhere "in the middle" between classical algebraic geometry and scheme theory would be best. For that, I would recommend these notes.

This is a subjective question with a subjective answer.
Before talking about algebra, I should also say that comfortability with essential category theory - manipulating adjunctions, the calculus of units and counits, functors, equivalences,... - and the notion of a sheaf is essential for learning scheme-based algebraic geometry (which most of it - outside of more modern research - is). Most books will try to motivate sheaves for you, but won't spend that long on it. If you want another perspective on sheaves and sheaf cohomology - in a topological, rather than geometric, context - I recommend Iversen's "Cohomology of Sheaves". For basic category theory, in my opinion absolutely nothing beats Tom Leinster's "Basic Category Theory".
From my own experience and what I've heard of others, the way it tends to go is that you will never know all the 'necessary' commutative algebra for algebraic geometry. It's the kind of thing you keep going back to. Indeed Hartshorne makes a point of black-boxing as much commutative algebra as possible... and his references are to things found neither in Hungerford nor Atiyah-Macdonald (sometimes) but also Matsumara and Zarisk-Samuel. If you really wanted to rigorously check everything Hartshorne is saying, you will need several commutative algebra books by your side.
But that said, algebraic geometry is the kind of subject where you (maybe) don't want to learn everything in maximal detail the first time you see it. My two cents are: (i) Atiyah-Macdonald is an excellent and very readable reference which you should probably read through (it doesn't take too long, if you give it a light once-over) but expect to keep coming back to and (ii) it won't be good enough for everything in Hartshorne, but Hartshorne is difficult enough to read as it is without also checking every single commutative algebra reference he makes, so be ready to black-box some things or, if a particular result really interests you, get a multitude of different algebra references to help you follow. My third cent might be that last comment applied to geometry as well: it's helpful to have multiple sources for algebraic geometry, because it's pretty difficult to learn unless you have a specific, focused goal in mind and it's nice to experience other people's presentations.
Qing Liu's book "Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves" is pretty good in that it gives reasonably detailed expositions of some of the necessary commutative algebra, far more so than Hartshorne's book, but I still found myself needing Atiyah-Macdonald and other sources by my side (... and even then, it was often hard to read - that's just the way of it). Gortz-Wedhorn is also highly recommended, Eisenbud and Harris,... Vakil's FOAG, ... not everyone likes Hartshorne or benefits from their writing style, so again be willing to check the other great resources.

Thank you so much for your recommendation. From your answer, it’s obvious algebraic geometry is huge and can’t be done as traditional undergraduate courses (like black box certain result and read a book “linearly”). For now, I think, I should only focus on commutative algebra from A&M. This is my first time trying to do a course whose content is not so straightforward and require massive background knowledge.
